# Hibernate resource leak in my code

Tags: hibernate

I appear to have a “leak” of some Hibernate resources in my code.
**Pseudo code**
For each of 20,000+ records
   Find a record using Criteria with an example entity
Add a new object to a collection on the entity
Save the entity with the new object to the database

**Issue**
The find with example entity fails at record 12,764.  If I execute just that find in a test case, it is retrieved successfully.  If I break the input file up into multiple files with 10,000 records each, all records are processed.
Here is a the code I am using to find the database record

```
try {
    // begin transaction
    ses = Activator.getSession();
    ses.beginTransaction();

    // find the object
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
    Example example = Example.create(exampleInstance);
    for (String exclude : excludeProperty) {
        example.excludeProperty(exclude);
    }
    crit.add(example);
    foundEntities =  crit.list();

    for (T curT : foundEntities) {
        this.initHibernateEntity((I) curT);
    }

    // commit transaction
    ses.getTransaction().commit();
} catch // all exceptions
finally {
    if (ses != null && ses.isOpen()) {
            ses.close();
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on where this might be.

Comment: Some stack trace would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are hitting a page-limit/concurrency-lock problem - and all of that work is being performed in one transaction. Is there any reason to not perform in smaller batches (like 10,000 - as you mentioned) and aggregate result?

[Decent Resources](http://martin.podval.eu/2010/12/nhibernate-performance-isssues-insert.html)

Comment: Thanks for the time and the link to the blog.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best parts of StackOverflow is the effort to get a problem down small enough to post.  I quite frequently find the answer in that process without ever posting.

Unfortunately, this time I found my own mistake after posting.  The issue was a combination of bad legacy data and poor log messages on my part.

I hope that you did not spend much time looking at the code.